# I can't modify variables I declared in C++ with UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere) using Blueprint (UE4)

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm new to UE4 but I have some basic understanding to C++ and I've been developing a FPS Shooter Game which is kinda challenging to me. And here I am, with a problem that is still remain unsolved to me.

So here's a part my code:

FPSCharacter.h:

```
#pragma once

...
#include "Weapon.h"
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Character.h"
#include "FPSCharacter.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class GAME_API AFPSCharacter : public ACharacter
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
...
    
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Weapon")
    UWeapon* Primary;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Weapon")
    UWeapon* Secondary;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Weapon")
    UWeapon* Tertiary;

...
};
```

Weapon.h (Which I think it doesn't matter in this case, but still):

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Item.h"
#include "Weapon.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class GAME_API UWeapon : public UItem
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:

    UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Item")
    float MagSize = 30.f;

    UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Item")
    float FireRate;

    UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Item")
    float BulletRange = 100000000.f;

    UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Item")
    float BaseDamage = 35.f;

    UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Item")
    float DamageDropRate = 0.8f;

protected:

    virtual void Use(class AFPSCharacter* Character) override;
    
};
```

And then I have some Blueprint classes created base on the UWeapon class waiting to be assigned to those three variables on `FPSCharacter.h` which are `UWeapon* Primary`, `UWeapon* Secondary` and `UWeapon* Tertiary`.

As what I intended, I went into FPSCharacter's Blueprint class and assigned those three variables to the Blueprint class I created just for them.

Modifying those values:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpCcc.jpg

Clicking the compile button:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXkbp.jpg

After clicking the compile button, all of those variables just went back to default. (With value None)

What is wrong with this? Did I do anything wrong? Please help me with this issue. Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `Instanced` keyword to UPROPERTY specifiers of weapon variables. That way, an instance of an object will be created and assigned to a property, that saves correctly

You might also need to add `EditInlineNew` as a UCLASS specifier to your weapon class.

FPSCharacter.h

```
UCLASS()
class GAME_API AFPSCharacter : public ACharacter
{
     // Other code...

     UPROPERTY(Instanced, EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Weapon")
     UWeapon* Tertiary;
}
```

Weapon.h

```
UCLASS(EditInlineNew)
class GAME_API UWeapon : public UItem
{
    // Weapon stuff
}
```

Comment: That worked! Do you care to explain how ```EditInlineNew``` works?

Comment: @HaiQin You can find more about it here:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/GameplayArchitecture/Classes/Specifiers/index.html

Indicates that Objects of this class can be created from the Unreal Editor Property window, as opposed to being referenced from an existing Asset. The default behavior is that only references to existing Objects may be assigned through the Property window). This Specifier is propagated to all child classes; child classes can override this with the NotEditInlineNew Specifier.